# Line chart not showing in mat-tab (angular material)

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, d3.js

i'm trying to plot line chart and integrate that in Mat-tab module. The issue what i'm facing is , the line chart is not getting shown on the tab section but its getting displayed when i use it outside of tabs(mat-tab)section.. here is my code

//Below is linechart.component.ts file

```
import { formatCurrency, formatDate } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import * as d3Scale from 'd3';
import * as d3Shape from 'd3';
import * as d3Array from 'd3';
import * as d3Axis from 'd3';
import { format } from 'd3';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-lc',
  templateUrl: './lc.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./lc.component.css']
})
export class LcComponent implements OnInit {

  public data: any[] = [
    {id:1, Dt:'2011-01-01', price:201}, //'%Y-%m-%d'
    {id:2, Dt:'2011-01-04', price:306},
    {id:3, Dt:'2011-01-09', price:254},
    {id:4, Dt:'2011-01-13', price:272},
    {id:5, Dt:'2011-01-15', price:290},
    {id:6, Dt:'2011-01-19', price:380},
    {id:7, Dt:'2011-01-21', price:105},
    {id:8, Dt:'2011-01-23', price:406},
    {id:2, Dt:'2011-01-25', price:306},
    {id:3, Dt:'2011-01-29', price:254},
    
  ];
  private margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50};
  private width: number;
  private height: number;
  private x: any;
  private y: any;
  private svg: any;
  private line!: d3Shape.Line<[number, number]>; // this is line defination

  constructor() {
    this.width = 900 - this.margin.left - this.margin.right;
    this.height = 600 - this.margin.top - this.margin.bottom;

    
   }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.buildChart();
  }

  public buildChart() {

    this.data = this.data.map((d: { Dt: string | number | Date; price: string | number; }) => ({Dt: new Date(d.Dt),
      price: +d.price
      }))
    // Define Scales
  this.x = d3Scale.scaleTime().rangeRound([0, this.width]);
  this.y = d3Scale.scaleLinear().rangeRound([this.height, 0]);
  this.x.domain(d3Array.extent(this.data, (d) => d.Dt ));
  this.y.domain(d3Array.extent(this.data, (d) => d.price ))

  

  this.svg = d3.select('svg#brNavChrt') // svg element from html
               .attr("width",900)
               .attr("height", 700)
               .append('g')   // appends 'g' element for graph design
               .attr('transform', 'translate(' + this.margin.left + ',' + this.margin.top + ')')
               
  const xAxis = d3Axis.axisBottom(this.x)
  const yAxis = (d3Axis.axisLeft(this.y).ticks(20,"$"))
  // Configure the X Axis
  this.svg.append('g')
          .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + this.height + ')')
          // .call(d3Axis.axisBottom(this.x))
          .call(xAxis)
  
  this.svg.append("text")
          .attr("x", this.width/2)
          .attr("y", this.height + this.margin.bottom)
          .style("text-anchor","middle")
          .text("Date");
  // confifure the Y-Axis
  this.svg.append('g')
          .attr('class', 'axis--y')
          // .call((d3Axis.axisLeft(this.y)).ticks(50,"$"))
          .call(yAxis)
  // adding label to y axis
  this.svg.append("text")
          .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
          .attr("y", 0-this.margin.left)
          .attr("x", 0-(this.height/2))
          .attr("dy","1em")
          // .tickSize(15)
          .style("text-anchor", "middle")
          .text("brNAV ($)");

// text label for title
  this.svg.append("text")
          .attr("class", "title")
          .attr("y", 0-(this.margin.top/2))
          .attr("x", this.width/2)
          .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
          .style("font-size","12px")
          .style("font-weight","bold")
          .style("text-decoration","underline")
          .text("Brocker Account Chart");
  // Chart
  this.line = d3Shape.line()
  .x( (d: any) => this.x(d.Dt) )
  .y( (d: any) => this.y(d.price) )
  // Configuring line path
  this.svg.append('path')
      .datum(this.data)
      .attr('class', 'line')
      .attr('d', this.line)
      .on("mouseleave", (d: any) => { 
        d3.select('#tooltip')
        .style("display", "none")
      })
      .on("mouseenter", (d: any) => { 
        d3.select('#tooltip')
        // .append('text')
        .attr('d',this.y(d.price))
        .style("display", "circle")
      })
 

  }
}
```

html file

```
<p>lc works!</p>
<div>
    <mat-tab-group>
        <mat-tab class="tab1" label="Home">
            <h2>Table Content</h2>
        </mat-tab>
        <mat-tab label="Daya">
        <!-- <md-content> -->
            <h2>Table Content1</h2>
            <hr>
            <svg id="brNavChrt" width=900, height=600></svg>
        
        <!-- </md-content> -->
    </mat-tab>
    </mat-tab-group>
</div>
<hr>
<div id="tooltip"></div>
<div>
    <svg id="brNavChrt"></svg>
</div>
```

Css code for styling

```
#brNavChrt {
    width: 900;
    height: 600;

}

::ng-deep .line {
    fill:none;
    stroke: #ffab00;
    stroke-width: 3;
    stroke-linejoin: round;
}

#tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    pointer-events: none;
    background:rgb(210, 252, 176);
    border: 0.1rem solid rgb(19, 7, 177);
    color: rgb(6, 8, 153);
    text-align: left;
}
 
#tooltip {
    padding:0.3rem;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    font-weight: normal;
    display: none;
    background:rgb(210, 252, 176);
    border: 0.1rem solid rgb(19, 7, 177);
    color: rgb(6, 8, 153);
    text-align: left;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    white-space: pre;
    opacity: 0.87;
}

.mat-tab-group {
  background-color: #FFF5EE;
  border: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  /* display: inline-block; */
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: There is a lot of noise here. Its hard to see where a problem might be, mixing so many things together.

Comment: @BjarneGerhardt-Pedersen: Thanks for your response and sorry for the noise in the code. My intention was to show the entire flow of the code. The issue what i'm facing is on the HTML- Mat-tab section. when i render svg chart its not getting displayed on the web, where as the same plot is showing outside the mat-tab tags. Let me know you nee d some details

Comment: Adding the stackbliz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rretzc?file=src%2Fapp%2Flc%2Flc.component.ts